# COUNTING COMMISSION

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Morning

I would like to combine text and formula's for example it would star Hi, and then take the info from the sale sheet by date cell B2 then continue with text blah blah blah and then insert another formula from the sale sheet by date cell H2 and then continue with text blah blah blah

Thank you in advance for any help given

Comment: Is "sale sheet by date" the name of the worksheet holding the data cells?

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

`="Hi " & Sales!B2 & " blah " & Sales!H2 & " blah."`

**OR**

`=CONCAT("Hi ",Sales!B2," blah ",Sales!H2," blah.")`

**OR**

`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,"Hi",Sales!B2,"blah",Sales!H2,"blah.")`

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating text can be done in a formula, using `&` or `TEXTJOIN()`:

```
=A1&A2
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;A1:A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly.

You can use

```
="Hi " & B2 & " blah blah blah blah" & (X2*3% + 2*Y99)
```

The `&` operator will concatenate strings (and it will tranform numeric cell into strings. You may need to use other functions, if you want to control format)